# How do I get ē, Ð, and such in a Perpetua document?

Tags: fontspec, accents

They have specified Perpetua (13pt), which is not ideal, but workable. However I have no idea how to go about diacritics more intricate than í.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontspec} % compile w/XeLaTeX
\setmainfont{Perpetua}
\usepackage[T1,noenc]{tipa}
\usepackage{tipx}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{main.bib} 

\begin{filecontents*}{main.bib}
    @article{fiketPromisesChallengesDeliberative2022,
        title = {Promises and {{Challenges}} of {{Deliberative}} and {{Participatory Innovations}} in {{Hybrid Regimes}}: {{The Case}} of {{Two Citizens}}’ {{Assemblies}} in {{Serbia}}},
        author = {Fiket, Irena and Đorđević, Biljana},
        date = {2022},
        journaltitle = {Filozofija i Društvo},
        volume = {33},
        number = {1},
        pages = {3--25},
        doi = {10.2298/FID2201003F},
        url = {https://doi.org/10.2298/FID2201003F},
        urldate = {2023-01-20}
    }

    @inbook{cesnulaityteKeyTrends2020,
        title = {Key {{Trends}}},
        booktitle = {Innovative {{Citizen Participation}} and {{New Democratic Institutions}}: {{Catching}} the {{Deliberative Wave}}},
        author = {Česnulaitytė, Ieva},
        date = {2020},
        edition = {first edition},
        pages = {67--79},
        publisher = {{OECD Publishing}},
        location = {{Paris, France}},
        url = {https://doi.org/10.1787/57c233e7-en},
        bookauthor = {{Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development}},
        isbn = {978-92-64-72590-4},
        chapter = {3}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    d\textipa{\=e}ēmokratí\textipa{\=a}ā and deliberation \cite{fiketPromisesChallengesDeliberative2022,cesnulaityteKeyTrends2020}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

References are synced with Zotero, but I don't think that matters a great deal. Any thoughts?

Comment: your document errors, fontspec doesn't know the option T1, you are confusing it with fontenc. I don't have your font and so can't tell you which glyphs it supports.

Comment: If you mean the Perpetua font that comes with Microsoft Office applications, then it lacks a lot of characters. Faking them with IPA is not really a good method anyway. Change font.

Comment: You don’t say who “they” are, but [MyFonts](https://www.myfonts.com/collections/perpetua-font-monotype-imaging?tab=glyphs) shows only 639 glyphs even in Perpetua **Pro** Roman. That’s few for a document with “intricate diacritics.” I see marks which could be pressed into service as combining diacritics, but it’s not clear that they’re properly encoded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. The Perpetua font provided by Microsoft Office applications lacks an awful lot of characters.

If you have just a few of them missing and don't try to use them in styles other than upright, here's a way to fake them.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{fiketPromisesChallengesDeliberative2022,
  title = {Promises and Challenges of Deliberative and Participatory Innovations in 
           Hybrid Regimes: The Case of Two Citizens’ Assemblies in {Serbia}},
  author = {Fiket, Irena and Đorđević, Biljana},
  date = {2022},
  journaltitle = {Filozofija i Društvo},
  volume = {33},
  number = {1},
  pages = {3--25},
  doi = {10.2298/FID2201003F},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.2298/FID2201003F},
  urldate = {2023-01-20},
}

@inbook{cesnulaityteKeyTrends2020,
  title = {Key Trends},
  booktitle = {Innovative Citizen Participation and New Democratic Institutions: 
               Catching the Deliberative Wave},
  author = {Česnulaitytė, Ieva},
  bookauthor = {{Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development}},
  date = {2020},
  edition = {first edition},
  pages = {67--79},
  publisher = {OECD Publishing},
  location = {Paris, France},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1787/57c233e7-en},
  isbn = {978-92-64-72590-4},
  chapter = {3},
}
\end{filecontents*}



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % compile w/XeLaTeX
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Perpetua}[
  Path=/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/Resources/DFonts/,
  BoldFont=* Bold,
  ItalicFont=* Italic,
  BoldItalicFont=* Bold Italic,
]

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\providecommand*\UndeclareTextComposite[3]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname\expandafter\string\csname
  #2\endcsname\string#1-#3\endcsname\relax}

\UndeclareTextComposite{\=}{TU}{a}
\UndeclareTextComposite{\=}{TU}{e}
\UndeclareTextComposite{\v}{TU}{C}
\UndeclareTextComposite{\'}{TU}{c}
\UndeclareTextComposite{\.}{TU}{e}

\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{TU}{a}{\fakebar{a}}
\newunicodechar{ā}{\=a}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\=}{TU}{e}{\fakebar{e}}
\newunicodechar{ē}{\=e}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\v}{TU}{C}{\accent"02C7 C}
\newunicodechar{Č}{\v{C}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\'}{TU}{c}{\accent"B4 c}
\newunicodechar{ć}{\'c}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\.}{TU}{e}{\fakedotabove{e}}
\newunicodechar{ė}{\.e}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\fakebar}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip\ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr\smash{-}\cr#1\cr}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\fakedotabove}[1]{%
  \leavevmode\vbox{\offinterlineskip\ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr.\cr\noalign{\vskip0.25ex}#1\cr}}%
}
\makeatletter
\DeclareTextCommand{\DJ}{TU}{%
  \leavevmode\makebox[0pt][l]{\kern-0.02em\raisebox{0.3ex}[0pt][0pt]{-}}D%
}
\DeclareTextCommand{\dj}{TU}{%
  d\makebox[0pt][r]{\raisebox{0.85ex}[0pt][0pt]{-}\kern-0.04em}%
}
\makeatother
\newunicodechar{Đ}{\DJ}
\newunicodechar{đ}{\dj}

\begin{document}

dēmokratíā and deliberation 

\cite{fiketPromisesChallengesDeliberative2022,cesnulaityteKeyTrends2020}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I removed almost all `{{...}}` parts in the bib file: they're wrong, except for one.

[image]

Comment: The double braces are likely caused because the OP has the title in title case in Zotero, where Zotero expects titles to be sentence case. If the OP changes the title to sentence case, the double braces will go away automatically.